# How do I create the html for the following enable/disable javascript to create a button to change the localstorage value?

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle, local-storage

I have the following javascript that cannot be changed.

Basically I need to make the UI for this, which is probably really basic html.

```
if(!localStorage.status) localStorage['status'] = 1;
toggle(2);
enable.onclick = function(){toggle(0)};
disable.onclick = function(){toggle(1)};
function toggle(n){
    if((n == 0) && (enable.parentNode == list)){
        list.removeChild(enable);
        list.appendChild(disable);
        localStorage.status = 1;
    }else if((n == 1) && (disable.parentNode == list)){
        list.removeChild(disable);
        list.appendChild(enable);
        localStorage.status = 0;
    }else if((n == 2) && (!list.hasChildNodes())){
        list.appendChild((localStorage.status == 1) ? disable : enable);
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: (localStorage.status == 1) ? "1.png" : "2.png"});
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

I think what it's doing is creating and enable/disable button. But I'm not sure.

Basically I need the html to display enable or disable, and on click it changes and updates the localstorage value for 'status'.

Remember we can't change the javascript, I just need the html.

_

Comment: so you need the toggle function to track if any status changes occur it would update the status variable in the local storage?

Comment: I believe so yes if I understood you correctly

Comment: the enable and disable refer to what ?

Comment: I just need the html to go along with this javascript

Comment: I think this will help: `list.removeChild(enable);` refers to `enable.onclick = function(){toggle(0)};`

Answer (score 1):

The quoted code requires variables `enable` and `disable` to be `HTMLElement` objects (so they can be `append`ed to `list`, which I assume is a `DIV`) that accept `click` events. So pretty much any kind of element will do.

However, it looks like `BUTTON`s would make the most sense, so I'd suggest creating the elements in javascript as

```
var enable = document.createElement("button"); //create a <BUTTON>
enable.id = "enable";
enable.type = "button";
enable.textContent = "Enable"; //the displayed text
```

and similarly for `disable`. If you'd prefer not to add additional scripts to the page, the equivalent HTML markup to use is

```
<button id="enable" type="button">Enable</button>
```

Comment: If you use HTML markup to create the button, you'll have to instantiate the javascript variable `enable` as well: `var enable = document.getElementById("enable");`

Comment: I tried `<button id="enable" type="button">Enable</button>` but clicking the button does nothing.

Comment: Also, you'll need the other button (`disable`) and an element called `list`, which the script swaps things into and out of.

Comment: If the above doesn't help you much, can I suggest reading the [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage#localStorage) docs?

Comment: no, the above doesn't work at all. It has nothing to do if it helps or not when it doesn't work. and no, appeandchild and localstorage docs are not going to help create the html.

Comment: not to mention you obviously didn't read the question because it's supposed to be ONE button not two.

Comment: @user2651403 - Jeremy's answer is correct.  Without two buttons, your JavaScript will throw an error complaining that `disable` is undefined.  There's enough in this answer to get what you need. If you don't know at least enough of HTML and JavaScript to understand what it does, then stackoverflow.com is not the right venue for your question.  Perhaps you should consider hiring a developer.  You might try [codementor.io](http://codementor.io/gilly3) to get some personalized assistance.  Either way, try to temper your frustration before responding rudely to someone who is trying to help you.